# Unable to create the database. The password might be incorrect or the database is not started

Tags: java, openmrs

I have downloaded the [OpenMRS](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-core) source code, and I am running it, as part of it I have run the below command

```
mvn jetty:run
```

then I am able to view the screen, but it is asking the my sql script, i have installed the my sql and it is showing the error like

> Unable to create the database. The password might be incorrect or the
>   database is not started.
>
> ???Error executing sql: create database if not exists `?` default

and I have verified that it is taking the runtime properties file from

```
C:\Users\Application Data\OpenMRS\openmrs-runtime.properties
```

But I didn't found this path in my local.

> character set utf8 - Could not create connection to database server.
>   Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.???